# Passing Client IP across Multiple Proxies

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, tomcat6

I have a load balancer in front of an Apache httpd server, which in turn is in front of a server running Tomcat6. We're using Tomcat to running Shibboleth's IdP. The follow looks like this:

```
Client -> Load Balancer -> Apache httpd server (mod_proxy_ajp) -> Tomcat server
```

I'm looking to pass the client's IP to the Tomcat server. The LB passes the variable `ClientIP` to the httpd server, which I can parse in httpd's LogFormat as `"%{ClientIP}i"`, but this obviously does not make it to the Tomcat server, instead Tomcat logs the IP of the LB.

I've tried using Tomcat's RemoteIpValve as (in `server.xml` insider `<Engine>`) :

```
> <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"   
> remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For"    protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto"
> protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />
```

hoping that the use of [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) would pass the IP in `X-Forwarded-For` without success. I've seen posts on `mod_rpaf`, but I'm hoping to do this without additional apache httpd mods.

I think I'm a couple of pieces away from tying all this together, but stuck in a rut. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the load balancer is inserting the client IP address in a header called ClientIP, mod_proxy should pass that on to the Tomcat sever without any special configuration. Try configuring the Tomcat RemoteIpValve to look for *ClientIP* instead of *X-Forwarded-For*. e.g.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
       remoteIpHeader="ClientIP"
       protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />
```

Comment: Thanks Vortura. I got the `ClientIP` logged into Tomcat's access logs by adjusting the `pattern` field, but I can't seem to get the `ClientIP` passed to the Shibboleth's IdP.  Perhaps that is a separate question (-; but you wouldn't happen to know Shibboleth's IdP, would you? (-: