# Logging X-Forwarded-For IP in Shibboleth's Audit Logs

Tags: tomcat, x-forwarded-for, shibboleth

This is a follow up from my earlier question on capturing the [X-Forwarded-For IP address in across multiple proxies](https://serverfault.com/questions/515707/passing-client-ip-across-multiple-proxies). Now, I'm looking to capture the Client's IP in the application's (Shibboleth's IdP) logs.

The follow is:

```
Client > Load Balancer > Apache httpd server > Tomcat server (running Shibboleth's IdP)
```

The variable with the Client's IP at the Load Balancer is `ClientIP` which I can capture in the web server's logs using `LogFormat "%{ClientIP}i ... " and similarly in Tomcat's access logs using these in`server.xml`:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
remoteIpHeader="ClientIP" 
protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
directory="logs" 
prefix="localhost_access_log." 
suffix=".txt"
pattern="%{ClientIP}i %h %l %u %t %r %>s %b %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Now, I'm looking to capture this IP in Shibboleth's IdP audit logs. [This discussion](http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/X-Forwarded-For-on-the-IdP-td7270386.html) talks about using `mod_rpaf` for Apache but doesn't get into the details. I'm hoping to do without installing additional modules.

Looks like I'm missing a couple of (small?) pieces here. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging at LogBack's [documentation on logging client IPs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html#mis) and the [corresponding code for the MDCInsertingServletFilter servlet](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/helpers/MDCInsertingServletFilter.html#74), turns out you must use the `X-Forwarder-For` header.

We replaced `ClientIP` with `X-Forwarder-For` in the load balancer, updated `httpd.conf`'s `LogFormat` to log `X-Forwarder-For`, then updated Shibboleth's `logging.xml` file as follows for the audit logs:

```
<appender name="IDP_AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <File>/app/shibboleth-idp/logs/idp-audit.log</File>

  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <FileNamePattern>/app/shibboleth-idp/logs/idp-audit-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
  <Pattern>%msg|%X{req.xForwardedFor}|%n</Pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

We made similar changes to the idp-process as well<strike>, and **did not** have to update Tomcat's logging</strike>.

Hope this helps others.

**Edit 1: Tomcat Logging**

Turns out, after a while, the `X-Forwarded-For` IP address stopped appearing in Shib's IdP logs. We ended up adding the `RemoteIpValve` in tomcat and restarting. Looks like it is needed after all:

```
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
   remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For"
   trustedProxies="--IPs here--"
   protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure `%X{req.xForwardedFor}` is needed. When you use the Tomcat `RemoteIpValve`, it will set `request.remoteAddr` to the value of the `X-Forwarded-For` header, then it unsets the `X-Forwarded-For` header. So in logging.xml you would use `%mdc{clientIP}` (which shouldn't be needed because `%msg` includes the client IP). For more info: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html (scroll down to the samples)

Comment: @bmaupin thanks for weighing in. It has been a while since we got this working, but I faintly recall the only (or the first perhaps?) combination to log the actual IP was  MDC filter + Tomcat valve + `X-Forwarded-For`. I don't recall any combination of `clientIP` working. The app has since moved to another platform, still this might be worth a second look.

Comment: Ah, yes if you're using the MDC filter that might change things. On my end all I needed was 1. `X-Forwarded-For` in the load balancer 2. `RemoteIpValve` in the Tomcat server.xml, then the client IP showed up fine in the Shibboleth logs.